# PTV Developer Routing API OpeningInterval is not applied

Tags: rest, ptv-developer

Im trying to calculate a route from Berlin to Rome using the Routing API with an openingInterval specified for the waypoint in Rome.
The openingInterval is not used, instead I’m getting a route violation for the openingInterval.

My request:

```
https://api.myptv.com/routing/v1/routes?options[trafficMode]=AVERAGE&options[startTime]=2022-01-25T13:00:00&results=VIOLATION_EVENTS,SCHEDULE_EVENTS

Body:
{
    "waypoints": [
        {
            "offRoad": {
                "latitude": 52.461790,
                "longitude": 13.324184
            }
        },
        {
            "offRoad": {
                "latitude": 41.889511,
                "longitude": 12.381591,
                "openingIntervals": [
                    {
                        "start": "2022-01-25T10:00:00",
                        "end": "2022-01-25T20:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "distance": 1508861,
    "travelTime": 68832,
    "violated": true,
    "events": [
        {
            "latitude": 52.461790044,
            "longitude": 13.324184073,
            "startsAt": "2022-01-25T13:00:00+01:00",
            "distanceFromStart": 0,
            "travelTimeFromStart": 0,
            "countryCode": "DE",
            "utcOffset": 60,
            "schedule": {
                "duration": 0,
                "scheduleTypes": [
                    "SERVICE"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "latitude": 41.889511025,
            "longitude": 12.381590967,
            "startsAt": "2022-01-26T08:07:12+01:00",
            "distanceFromStart": 1508861,
            "travelTimeFromStart": 68832,
            "countryCode": "IT",
            "utcOffset": 60,
            "violation": {
                "type": "SCHEDULE",
                "scheduleViolationTypes": [
                    "OPENING_INTERVAL"
                ]
            },
            "schedule": {
                "duration": 0,
                "scheduleTypes": [
                    "SERVICE"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The routing should arrive at around 7am in Rome and have to wait there for the openingInterval, but instead the route finishes without waiting.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all waypoints are always open per default as soon as you set openingIntervals the waypoint will only be open during these intervals and closed otherwise.
In your case you are arriving on the next day since your route is quite long, while your openingInterval is specified for the same day.
If you don’t know if you will arrive on the same day you started the route, I suggest adding the openingInterval for the next day as well, like this:

```
{
"waypoints": [
    {
        "offRoad": {
            "latitude": 52.461790,
            "longitude": 13.324184
        }
    },
    {
        "offRoad": {
            "latitude": 41.889511,
            "longitude": 12.381591,
            "openingIntervals": [
                {
                    "start": "2021-01-25T10:00:00",
                    "end": "2021-01-25T20:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "start": "2021-01-26T10:00:00",
                    "end": "2021-01-26T20:00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}